# react native possible uhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

im getting the following errors
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: user.slice is not a function. (In 'user.slice()', 'user.slice' is undefined)

I need the code to be able to pass the data too return the list of users in order of most matching elements to least. I was able to get the function working in replit with a made up data base once I try to put it in my project I am getting trouble, please help.

```js
 auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
            const profile = getUserProfile(user.uid);
            profile.then(pro => {
              const addy = pro.Address;
              setAddress(pro.Address);


              const filterdUsers = FBusers.filter(user => {
                if(user.Address === addy && user.uid !== p  pro.uid){
                  
                    const items = new Set(pro)
                    
                    const rank = arr => arr.filter(user => items.has(user)).length
                    
                    return (a, b) => rank(b.items) - rank(a.items)
              
                  
                }
                  const sorted = user.slice().sort(filterdUsers(pro))
                  
                  console.log(sorted.map(user => user.items.join(', ')))
                }
              )}};
              // sort users
              //setUsers(sortByMatch);
              //vvv delete me vvv
              setUsers(filterdUsers);
```

Comment: Why do you think the Firebase Auth user object should have a method called slice?  The error message is telling you that it doesn't.  It's not wrong about that.

Comment: Please edit the question if you will so that the code compiles without syntax errors. Indenting closing curly braces (`}`) under the start of the line or expression that opened the  `{}`  pair is another way to help people read what the code is  doing.

Answer (score 0):

user is an object here and you can't slice an object. You can only slice an array or string

[JavaScript Array Slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

[JavaScript String slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp)